# How do I trigger transition after merging into branch

Tags: github, triggers, jira

I have specific workflow in Jira:
**TODO** > **In progress** > **Ready for deployment** > **Testing** > **Ready for production**

Under Workflows I can set custom transitions and triggers between these statuses.

E.g. Task is in **TODO**. User creates new branch with jira_task key. Task transitions from **TODO** into **In progress**.

What I need now, is to have a transition between **In progress** and **Ready for deployment** if "*feature*" branch was merged into release. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "Pull Request" trigger can handle that. See here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/blog/2015/07/workflow-automation-triggers

Comment: I need status to change only after merging to specific branch :/ so it won't work